# Open litespeed and additional engines in subfolders

Tags: directory, litespeed, open

Last night I spent more time than I should have trying to get a. New VDS up and running with percona and open litespeed. The site I want to run ok there is structured as follows

Webroot
- index.php
- wordpressfolder
- forum

When you go to domain.mysite it shows the wordpress site and achieved this through rewrite rules. (This is the Wordpress in it's own folder tutorial on wp.org) I keep things in folders for cleanliness. The wordpress site worked fine as I was able to paste the rewrite rules into open lite speed web interface.

Things failed to work however when I go to domain/forum.

I can get the index to show but clicking on any forum links redirects me to the wordpress 404.

I created a new context under the main virtual host.

Uri: /forum/
Directory: /path/to/forum
Rewrite: on
Inherit: no
Rewrite rules: pasted my mybb rewrite rules with google SEO plugin
Rewrite base: /forum/

I also tried with several different bases and uri. I also tried the uri to just a / it returns the forum index page which seems like some progress. I also tried altering the rewrite rules to have / for the second parameter but that didn't help either.

I have scratched the server but will be building it again and am leaning towards this as an option instead of centmin mod and was wondering if anyone may have an idea how to handle this?

Oh the context type I setup was a static context

Answer (score 0):

This question was actually answered on the [OpenLiteSpeed.com forum](http://openlitespeed.com/threads/need-help-with-contexts-and-rewrite-rules-for-different-app-installs-under-same-vhost.316/#post-950). Here's the changes we made there:

We took his basic WordPress rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/index.php [L]
```

and added a line to tell them to not rewrite when the requested URI is the forum:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/index.php [L]
```

It seems to have fixed things.

m